# Why not include data into a SMPS?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, mains, power-line-communication

Something I have been thinking that could drastically reduce the cost of powerline devices in a bridge that uses the switching circuit to provide both regulation and data.

Basically you could have a wifi, bluetooth, homeplug 230Vac low voltage bridge.
This would allow a simple 16 device master/slave 12v DC side for sensors and devices with extremely simple low cost powerline data embedded and created by the already existing SMPS circuitry.

The cost saving on end points could be huge as a very simple data line of a strong signal could be used and multiplexed into power usage.

Would be prefect form for LED lighting to home control systems.

Comment: Now all you have to do is convince all the patent holders that the product should be cheap.

Comment: Do you mean parasitic devices that live on power derived from the communications medium? If that is the case I once powered "a" 286 based RTU on a modified 2 wire RS485 transmission  line. It worked but did not seem practical at the time.

Comment: Have at it, Stuart.

Comment: Take it to Kickstarter. We don't judge (much).

Comment: Nah not parasitic power, the inverse actually. I don't believe in IP so sod that one :)
I don't have the math but it is possible to have an asynchronous data comms where a ripple current could carry data and the smps would basically average the packet.
Probably much cheaper than zwave or zigbee as that would be bridge side, this also has much less RF.
Anyway someone nick the idea if the can make something of it.
The ripple current would be a strong down signal and the return signal would be processed by the more complex bridge circuitry.
Meaning end devices can be much cheaper.

Comment: I can barely understand what's being discussed here. Can someone please translate this question using more concise engineering terms?

Comment: This sounds a little like the DCC system used for model trains.

Comment: It is very like DCC and yeah why has noone ever bridged more complex data buses to something much more basic as DCC as like DCC I presume the rational is the end device is of low complexity and low cost.

Comment: Have you heard about Power over Ethernet? I think this standard is the closest to your idea